# How to store multiple product under one shop? How to manage certain situation in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I guys, i'm working on a e-commerce website where in, Mysql i got two tables. Products and Shops now i have condition where, i need to add Multiple product under one shop in my shop table. i'm confused how to figure out this thing. please give soltion or atleast Table structure so that, i can implement according to that.
i need table colum structure thank you.

Comment: Presumably, you need a junction table with name like `ShopProducts`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thnks, i got clear idea from what u said.! :)

Answer (score 1):

this might be the shop table in simplest form:
id,shopname

this might be the product table structure in simplest form:
id,product_name,shop_id

you have for example 5 shops, in your shops table.
Every time a user want to insert a product into the products table you should have an option where the user can select the shop or you should do it automatically by getting the shop-id according to the page where the user is.
At the end you have for example 5 shops in shops table and 200 products in your products table. Each product has a shop id which indicates to what shop it belongs.

Now you cant query in your products table simply by selecting all products with a specific shop id eg. "SELECT * FROM products WHERE shop_id=$anyvariable";

I hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

No one is doing the work for you. We can help you if you need.

Why you need to add products in the shop table? If you want to add Multiple products for same shop. you can have a table like this

Shop table

[image: Shop table]
Product table
[image]

Here You can find w=hich product belong to which shop. The product1 and product2 belong to Myshop.

Refer to foreign keys[Techopedia Link](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/7272/foreign-key)

Comment: You appear to be doing the work for the OP. And, professional rivalry perhaps, but see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: Will change The w3schools link. But I have some time today, So i did made some sample tables. No big deal

Comment: @shobi thank u but, i know what you tried to shown above. in above product table i have product category column in which  my product categories has been stored already according to that i'm selecting products on front page. Now, in my case i want show product on front page without repeating them category wise. after that i need to show selected product on other page with available shop list.